# Problem with date when uploading a csv via DataLoader

Tags: data-loader, date

I'm having an issue when uploading a date from a csv via DataLoader.
The date on my csv is for example 2017-04-03, but when uploading it via DataLoader, it will be 2017-04-02 in SF (always one day less).

The SF field is a Date field, not Date/time.

Any idea of what could be the problem? I'm trying to check the DataLoader settings but I'm on MacOS and nothing happens when I click "Preferences".

Thanks,
/Y

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a timezone issue and will need to modify the PC's time zone.

Here is some information from a [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005099&language=en_US&type=1) with 2 possible solutions.

> Two simple solutions to this are:
>
> 1) Specify a time as well as a date when loading dates using the Data Loader
>
> 2) Switch your PC's time zone to Hawaiian time before starting up the Data Loader.

Comment: Thanks, adding a time works, but changing my MAC's time zone didn't.

Comment: Cool. Sounds like SF is expecting DateTime from your load. Glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below date format to upload data through data loader:
mm/dd/yyyyThh:mm:ssZ